# spring boot - swap values in column with unique constraint

Tags: spring, hibernate, h2

In my web app I want enable users to sorting contacts on their own.

So i have a table 'Contact' and column 'order_contact' with unique contraint.

Method to update rows looks:

```
public void updateOrder(List<ContactLightDto> dtosToUpdate) {
        List<Contact> entitiesToUpdate = dtosToUpdate.stream().map(it -> {
            Contact entity = repository.findByContactName(it.getContactName()).orElseThrow();
            return entity.withOrderContact(it.getOrderContact());
        }).toList();
        repository.flush();
        repository.saveAll(entitiesToUpdate);
    }
```

To clarify, dtosToUpdate are objects with new order to update existing contacts. When one order is increasing, then antoher is decreasing. For example user replaced first contact with second one.(1 -> 2, 2 -> 1).

I set flush mode( spring.jpa.properties.org.hibernate.flushMode )to COMMIT. So code dosent generate problem with findByContactName() method when selecting unique 'order_contact' and having already 'dirty' entity with given orderContact.

Next im flushing changes to DB, and when im invoking saveAll() method im getting:

```
exception is :could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint ["PUBLIC.CONSTRAINT_INDEX_63 ON PUBLIC.CONTACT(ORDER_CONTACT NULLS FIRST) VALUES ( /* 1 */ 1 )"; SQL statement:
update contact set contact=?, contact_name=?, order_contact=?, creator_id=? where id=? [23505-214]]
```

I didn't find good solution. I see options:

1. give random orders, flush changes and then replace with good ones to ommit problems with unique constraint.
2. initially deferred constraint - im currently developing in h2, and i didnt see possibility to use that.
3. replace entity properties and dont touch order - latest thought.

Anyone know good solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

i did this be change code to

```
public void updateOrder(List<ContactLightDto> dtosToUpdate) {
    List<Contact> entitiesToUpdate = dtosToUpdate.stream().map(it -> {
        Contact entity = repository.findByContactName(it.getContactName()).orElseThrow();
        return entity.withOrderContact(it.getOrderContact());
    }).toList();

    repository.deleteAllById(entitiesToUpdate.stream().map(Contact::getId).toList());
    repository.flush();
    repository.saveAll(entitiesToUpdate);
}
```

Its working, but its generating a lot of queries to db.